# Why does Intranet site NOT cache form values but same site deployed to Internet does?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, browser-cache, intranet

I have a form in a ASPX page that saves & retains content after submission so that it can be cloned again with minor changes to some fields. This feature is built to save data entry time.

This Save form & Keep content functionality works fine when it works in a Intranet setting. However when this site is deployed to the Internet for public access, the form behaves inconsistently.

The form submission works fine a few times (this number keeps varying) - it saves form values & retains the same content, but later randomly shows values from previous data entries.

For example, in a form of 5 fields to store product info, I may choose to change just the title. The first time if I fill the value "Product 1" for the title field, it will save it & continue to display the same field values. Continuing this process, when I try to modify the title to "Product 5", it may not save that record & show "Product 3" instead of retaining "Product 5" as expected.

Has this anything to do with some ViewState size limit or some IIS cache setting or due to it being deployed to a Farm? Can anyone explain why a form within a site that works on the Intranet doesn't work similarly when it is published as a Internet site?

Comment: Are you retaining and loading values to controls on server side? which event?

Comment: Based on behavior you describe, I'd say it was due to the farm.  Can you give us some detail how you persist the form data? Also: Your very last sentence seems opposite to your question title.

Comment: @Imran Rizvi After saving the form values, the user is redirected to the same page but the form values are not cleared so the previously entered values stay where there are.

Comment: @GuthMD  The form values are purposely not cleared so the previously entered values stay where there are. You are right & sorry for the confusion - the title should be "Why does Intranet site NOT cache form values but same site deployed to Internet does?" I'll see if I can edit it now

Comment: You say "the user is redirected to the same page".  Is it an actual redirect, or a postback?

Comment: If it is a postback, the ViewState should keep the values without any code at all.  Could you post the code for the Save form and Keep content functionality?

Comment: @KennyZ Yes, the ViewState is keeping the values.  Save form and Keep content code is regular ADO.NET code to simply saves form values to db.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Session State for this and the application is deployed to a load-balanced farm, then you need to configure session state to use SQL Server.

What is happening is that which session you are hitting depends on what box you are hitting, so when the postback hits a different server it gets whatever is in the session on that server.

Here is an example from web.config as shown on MSDN :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
        source=SampleSqlServer;" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:
So, you are not using session state, and not touching the values anywhere in code.  That only leaves some sort of wierd caching thing.  Perhaps the server farm has cache settings that are not the same from machine to machine...that's the only way I can see that you would get the behavior you describe.

You may be able to override machine.config cache settings in your web.config.  Try:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime enableKernelModeCache="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not using Session State